# Would it be appropriate to create a better duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, canonical

Over in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), we get a lot of questions from (primarily new) users asking the same question of

> How can I access formA from formB?

To which of course there are numerous duplicates.. but the majority of these just give the code to fix the issue in one specific way, when there are a few options available, as well as other options that are valid depending on the framework being used.

So my question is this..

Would it be appropriate/acceptable for me to create a question that would give more definite/well-rounded answers for each version of framework (i.e WPF/Winforms) explaining all the options?

If yes,  should this answer/question be marked as a community wiki?

<sub>I realise this is written in a specific way but this could be applied to a few regularly asked questions</sub>

Comment: Creating a canonical question-answer pair is certainly appropriate and acceptable. Take into account that writing that beast is *hard* however! If you want an example of how it could be done, take a look at what the Python chatroom did with [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658); the post was prepared and discussed first before it was made a community wiki post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Awesome link (and response), cheers. Where was that post discussed and prepared first though? In the chatroom? No doubt it would be a big task but my hope is that their are those who get tired of the question just as much when using wpf/asp.net

Comment: In the chatroom, with support from our [chatroom site (link to a new post under discussion)](http://sopython.com/wiki/4/). We are actually planning to make the site software available as OSS so other chatrooms can use it too. See https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site

Comment: I've always liked this example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: This needs at least two questions one for winforms/wpf and another for "web"

Answer (score 4):

If none of the existing questions is general enough *and* has good, focused answers which make it a good canonical, feel free to go ahead and create a new canonical question and answer.

You might want to coordinate within your community.  If there is a [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [chat room](//chat.stackoverflow.com), bring it up there, ideally before investing time and effort -- there may be good canonicals which other users have bookmarked and/or authored which you were unable to find.

There is no requirement for your answer to be a [Community Wiki](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer.  If you put in substantial work to create it, you should deserve credit in the normal manner.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, right you are. Updated.